# android how to add ProgressBar to listView fetching data from parse?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-progressbar

I've looked everywhere for a tutorial, but couldn't find a tutorial that uses `ProgressBar`; they all use `ProgressDialog` which is simple but not in my need. So, can anyone give me an example?
Here's how I am setting the adapter:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new mainAdapter(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`ParseQueryAdapter` `getItemView()` class:

```
@Override
    public View getItemView(Campaign campaign, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_single,null);
        }

        super.getItemView(campaign, v, parent);

        ParseImageView mealImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
        ParseFile photoFile = campaign.getImage();
        if (photoFile != null) {
            mealImage.setParseFile(campaign.getImage());
            mealImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                    // nothing to do
                }
            });
        }
        else{

        }

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleTextView.setText(campaign.getTitle());
        TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.description);
        descriptionTextView.setText(campaign.getDescription());
        return v;

    }
```

Would be a pleasure if you didn't -1 without thinking. Thanks :)

Comment: 1.add a progress in R.layout.list_single. 2.when start load image ,setVisible(VISIBILE)3. when done, setVisible(GONE)

Answer (score 0):

ProgressBar's are pretty simple. In XML, I usually position them inside of a FrameLayout at the same level as the main content, such as a ScrollView.  In `done()` after your data has been fetched, hide the ProgressBar and show the ScrollView (or whatever view holds your main content).  Hope this helps.

EDIT: If fetching images, use INVISIBLE instead of GONE when hiding whatever layout/views contain your images while the ProgressBar is visible; otherwise the size of the images won't be calculated correctly.

Comment: I mean by a progress bar where the progress becomes visible when fetching the object, and then adds, when it is add %100,which happens when the image downloaded, it disappears

Comment: You need a custom layout for this. Add Progress bar to R.layout.list_single make it visible when download started and set the progress in GetDataCallback, when the download finishes make it invisible (or gone)

Comment: @aelimill but how do I make it add the percentage automatically?

Comment: Well, as i can see ParseImageView class do not have a method that have a ProgressCallback needed for displaying correct loading progress(you do not need an indeterminate progress, do you?), so you can make it yourself with ParseFile. It has a method getFileInBackground(GetFileCallback fileCallback, ProgressCallback progressCallback), make ProgressBar setProgress with the value received in ProgressCallback.

Comment: Why not just use a loading spinner (ProgressBar)?

Comment: @SeanThomas I need progressBar, and that's final.